# get the first row of mask that meets conditions and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, 21, 333, 444], 'b': [20, 20, 20, 20]})
```

I want to create column `c` by using this `mask`:

```
mask = (df.a >= df.b)
```

and I want to get the second row that meets this condition and create column `c`.
The output that I want looks like this:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20    x
2  333  20  NaN
3  444  20  NaN
```

And this is my try but it put 'x' on all rows after the first row:

```
df.loc[mask.cumsum().ne(1) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is to mark all matching rows but the first one (`mask.cumsum().ne(1)`).

If you want to mark only the second use:

```
mask = (df.a >= df.b)
df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(2) & mask, 'c'] = 'x'
```

Output:

```
     a   b    c
0   20  20  NaN
1   21  20    x
2  333  20  NaN
3  444  20  NaN
```